# Is it possible to append filebeat to ELK docker image without rebuilding it?

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, filebeat

I want to use the [elk](https://elk-docker.readthedocs.io/) image, it seems like the official one. So it has Logstash, elastic search, and Kiban, but it doesn't have filebeat, the docs says to install it separately. I found other very popular docker images like [this one](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) but none include filebeat.

I'd like to install it in the docker image so that I won't have to configure it and deploy it separately, it's cleaner that way.

I've read some posts that says, that you have to clone the image off github and change the docker makefile but I'd like to keep using the official image as is, so that if someone in my company wants to add filebeat, he pulls the official image off dockerhub and runs a command to add filebeat to it, is that possible?

I don't want to be responsible for maintaining the main docker image that the whole company uses.

Comment: Why do you need **Filebeat** to be in same container? The point of **ELK** architecture that **Filebeat** is just a client that sends data from your server. If you will install **Filebeat** on the same machine, it becomes you "server". What data do you plan to send out there to **ELK**? Usually you need to install **Filebeat** on other machine/sever/container/whatever like `nginx, apache, tomcat, mysql, or whatever` logs you want to parse and represent in Elastic.

Comment: @Alex To be totally honest with you, I don't know what filebeat, all I want to do is to send mysql data to elastic, I didn't like the idea of keep posting huge data through REST to elastic, I asked my cousin who's a programmer too, he said he uses logstash, and that seemed awesome, it could do whatever I want, and then I discovered that for some reason I don't know, people send data to logstash using filebeat, even though logstash is perfectly capable of reading logs, so I didn't get why people would use Filebeat, maybe so that they don't have to connect Logstash directly to Mysql by JDBC

Comment: @Alex , but well I thought, since that's what people do, I'll just include it in the same image. I was wrong it seems, thank you for clarifying what Filebeat is. I plan to send MYSQL data to elastic. That's all, SQL data

Comment: If I remember correctly you can read mysql directly from `Logstash`, you don't need `Filebeat` for that, if you mean read real database tables from `MySQL`

Comment: @Alex That's what I saw too, I don't think I need Filebeat, but everyone uses it